# R function to produce a year column

Tags: r

I am trying to produce a function that puts a year column in a dataframe.

I can do this without the function by using:

```
#Create a dataframe with some dates in it. 
y<-data.frame(Date=(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'),as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"), 20)))      

#create the year column
library(lubridate)
y$Year<-year(y$Date)
```

When I try to wrap this inside a function, nothing happens:

```
#Create a dataframe with some dates
x<-data.frame(Date=(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"), 20)))

#Create the function
yearfunction<-function(dataframe, datecolumn)
{dataframe$Year<- year(dataframe[,datecolumn])
}

#Call the function
yearfunction(x, "Date")
```

What I want to happen is to get the same results as in the first example. Can anyone help with how I can amend the function to achieve this?

Comment: You need to return the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the `yearfunction` like this

```
library(lubridate)

yearfunction<-function(dataframe, datecolumn) {
    year(dataframe[,datecolumn])
}

y$Year <- yearfunction(y, "Date")

y
#         Date Year
#1  2013-09-18 2013
#2  2013-09-26 2013
#3  2012-10-25 2012
#4  2012-05-14 2012
#5  2017-03-01 2017
#6  2016-07-10 2016
#7  2015-02-21 2015
#8  2010-07-28 2010
#9  2013-01-31 2013
#10 2012-01-31 2012
#.....
```

---

Or we can also use `transform` in the function

```
yearfunction<-function(dataframe, datecolumn) {
    transform(dataframe, Year = year(dataframe[,datecolumn]))
}

yearfunction(y, "Date")

#         Date year
#1  2013-09-18 2013
#2  2013-09-26 2013
#3  2012-10-25 2012
#4  2012-05-14 2012
#5  2017-03-01 2017
#6  2016-07-10 2016
#...
```